# How to change character in char array

Tags: c, arrays, char

My function gets a char array as input. If it includes character `e` it changes it with `a` and returns the new char array. Here is my code:

```
char echanger(char word[]){

    int total = 0;
    int i;
    char final[5];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(word[i]=='e'){
            final[i] == 'a';
        }
        else{
            final[i] == word[i];
        }
    }

    return final;
}
```

I call it in in `main()` function like this:

```
int main(){

    char a[] = "helle";
    printf("new string is: %d \n",echanger(a));

}
```

it gives me this output:

```
new string is: -48
```

what I'm missing in here?

Comment: I assume  final[i] == 'a'; must be  final[i] = 'a'; (ASSIGN not EVAL)

Comment: Your function is declared to return `char` but you're returning a `char` array.

Comment: Also you're trying to return a local variable, that gets destroyed by the end of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program has several errors. Assuming the string length. Not allowing for, or writing , the `nul` terminator. Not returning the pointer. Using `==` where you mean `=`. Trying to return a local variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *echanger(char *word) {
    int len = strlen(word);
    int i;
    char *final = malloc(len+1);
    for(i=0; i<=len; i++) {         // include terminator
        if(word[i] == 'e')
            final[i] = 'a';
        else
            final[i] = word[i];
    }
    return final;
}

int main(){
    char a[] = "helle";
    char *news;
    news = echanger(a);
    printf("new string is: %s\n", news);
    free(news);                     // was from malloc
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
new string is: halla
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just modify the original string instead of creating a new one?

```
void echanger(char word[]){

    int i;
    int n = strlen(word);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(word[i]=='e'){
            word[i] = 'a';
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** `=` is assignment. `==` is comparison.

**Also** you need to use the `%s` format specifier in `printf` to output strings. `%d` will try to read the string as an `int` which gives you the weird value.

**Also** FWIW `char final[5]` is not large enough to hold the C-string `"helle"`. Remember the terminating null character.

Comment: Note that my version returns void. You should now have something like `char a[] = "helle"; echanger(a); printf("%s\n", a);`

Comment: but i don't want to make it void?

Comment: Then make it return `char*` and allocate a new char array with `malloc`. That's the only way. However you would have a memory leak if you'd then do `printf("%s\n", echanger(a));` because you couldn't free the memory `echanger` allocated. Making it `void` and just modifying the parameter would be the safest way to do it. See Weather Vane's answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are using equality (`==`) operator instead of for assignment (`=`) operator. Change `final[i] == 'a'`  to `final[i] = 'a'`.

If I rewrite the function with the changes then it will be -

```
char echanger(char word[]){

    int total = 0;
    int i;
    char final[5];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(word[i]=='e'){
            final[i] = 'a';
        }
        else{
            final[i] = word[i];
        }
    }

    return final;
}
```

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes that's one problem. i think the other is i call it with %d I think i should use something else

Comment: Oh sure! In main method you can use %s.

Comment: This still doesn't work. You're returning a local variable. The return type is `char` but you're returning `char[5]`. I have no idea why that even compiles in C.